# What would be the impact on value of a country's assets and trade balance if its residents choose to increase their savings

Tags: international-economics

What would be the impact on value of a country's assets and trade balance if its residents choose to increase their savings by investing in overseas assets and why?
May please help with this question family.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does investment have a negative impact on the current account (trade balance)?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/29804/how-does-investment-have-a-negative-impact-on-the-current-account-trade-balance)

Answer (score -1):

An article on this topic:

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/022415/top-10-countries-save-most.asp

Generally economists would say that savings are bad for the growth because they decrease amount of money in the economy. Smaller group would say that savings are good because of higher stability, more thoughtful spending. There is no universal consensus on this question, but we can look at the data.

Countries where people save are usually less stable, get their money from resources. Probably this makes people realise that personal savings may improve stability. And low taxes make people save more too.

Data for europe and household savings:

https://howmuch.net/articles/saving-rates-around-the-world

It seems people save where they can. If they have growing income they save more. If they have large taxes or stagnation they save less. I dont know what will happen if people would change their saving behaivor contrary to the country's situation. If its too sharp change, economy would suffer, as with any change. If it is smooth, it could increase the growth, assuming international trade is significant enough to compensate reduced internal consumption.